# How to show Print preview in form control?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, wpf-controls

I can't figure out how to show print preview in control.

I have `class Printer : PrintDocument` that contains what I want to print but how to show that in form and in which control.

---

tried this and it works in windows forms application but I need something for WPF application. 
 Here I used PrintPreviewControl but I don't know how to show it in WPF form.
 Also I would prefer to use DocumentViewer to show preview.
 Can anyone help me with that?

```
     PrintPreviewControl ppc;
     //Here goes MouseDown I just used btn_Click for testing
     private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Printer p = new Printer();
         ppc = new PrintPreviewControl();
         ppc.Document = p;
         ppc.Location = new Point(10, 50);
         ppc.Width = 700;
         ppc.Height = 1000;
         ppc.Name = "PPC";

         this.Controls.Add(ppc);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
var printDialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();

printDialog.Document = new Printer();
printDialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: That opens new window with PrintDPreview. I want to have preview in the same window. When user selects document form list i want to show it's preview next to the list.